# Create variable of a generic class from a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a class that can keep a number between to values. Here for I have created my first two generic classes.

The first called LimitRang and keep two limit rang variables; one for the lower rang and for the top rang. The second called NumberLimitRang and keep the number and the first class LimitRang.

When I try to create the variable mvarRang, how is a LimitRang var, in the constructor of NumberLimitRang I receive the error : 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'VariableTypes.Supplement.LimitRang' to 'T'.

My code for LimitRang:

```
namespace VariableTypes.Supplement
{
/// <summary>
/// Manage the boundaries for a number.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The numberic type for the limit parameters</typeparam>
public class LimitRang<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private T mvarLowestLimitNumber;
    private T mvarHighestLimitNumber;

    /// <summary>
    /// The default constructor (between 0 and 100)
    /// </summary>
    public LimitRang()
    {
        if (Functions.IsNumericType(typeof(T)))
        {
            try
            {
                mvarLowestLimitNumber = (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(T));
                mvarHighestLimitNumber = (T)Convert.ChangeType(100, typeof(T));
            }
            catch
            {
                mvarLowestLimitNumber = default(T);
                mvarHighestLimitNumber = default(T);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

My code for NumberLimitRang:

```
 namespace VariableTypes
 {
 /// <summary>
 /// Can contain a number that need to be between or equal to two limit numbers
 /// </summary>
 public class NumberLimitRang<T> where T : IComparable
 {
     private Supplement.LimitRang<T> mvarRang;
     private T mvarNumber;

    /// <summary>
    /// The default constructor (between 0 and 100/Number = 0)
    /// </summary>
    public NumberLimitRang(T mvarRang)
    {
        mvarRang = new Supplement.LimitRang<T>();
        mvarNumber = (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(T));
    }
}
}
```

Even when I replace the two T's into int, I still receive the error:

```
-    private Supplement.LimitRang<int> mvarRang;

-        mvarRang = new Supplement.LimitRang<int>();
```

Can you tell me what I do wrong?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
public NumberLimitRang(T mvarRang)
{
    mvarRang = new LimitRang<T>();
    mvarNumber = (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(T));
}
```

You pass `mvarRang` as an argument and you have field with name `mvarRang`. But in method `NumberLimitRang` compiler uses `mvarRang` as argument, wich is type of `T` and tryes to replace it's value with `new LimitRang<T>();`.
So, first of all, rename field or argument. For example:

```
public class NumberLimitRang<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private LimitRang<T> _mvarRang;
    private T _mvarNumber;

    /// <summary>
    /// The default constructor (between 0 and 100/Number = 0)
    /// </summary>
    public NumberLimitRang(T mvarRang)
    {
        _mvarRang = new LimitRang<T>();
        _mvarNumber = (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

It's good practice to name fields with `_` in the beginning.

But now, your argument `mvarRang` is unused. Revise your logic in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public NumberLimitRang(T mvarRang)
{
    mvarRang = new Supplement.LimitRang<T>();
    mvarNumber = (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(T));
}
```

The constructor takes a variable `mvarRang` of type `T`. This declaration hides the instance member `mvarRang` of the type `LimitRang<T>`.

Either change the parameter name, or refer to the instance member explicitly using `this`:

```
public NumberLimitRang(T mvarRang)
{
    this.mvarRang = new Supplement.LimitRang<T>();
    mvarNumber = (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(T));
}
```